# Bra-ket notation typefaces

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, braket

I have been using the `braket` package for using the dirac bra-ket notation. I came across many old books, e.g. Dirac's Principles of quantum mechanics, which contain a different font or typeface for the bra-ket notation. I wanted to try writing a document for myself with such a typeface. I have tried the default latex font, Baskerville and a few others but was not able to find a similar bra and ket.  So my question is as follows: How can I obtain a similar looking bra and ket in latex.
For reference, an example of the bra and ket that I mention is given below:

[image]

Note

Comment: Are you looking for a different type face  or  macro  with a single`|` and a single `>`?

Comment: Both would be fine. I can define a command using | and > if that looks as mentioned!

Comment: You  should have a look at the  `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`  command from `mathtools`,  and its variants (`\DecalrePairedDelimiterX` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`).

Comment: For the bracket shape, there may be something of interest here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590937/different-symbol-scalerel-issue

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer or at least leave a comment when there is still a problem

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, this is exactly what I wanted. I have upvoted your answer on your post on the other page.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment, you can use `\DeclareMathDelimiter` from `mathtools` to define `\bra` and `\ket`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}

\begin{document}
\[ \bra{x} \ket{y} \quad \bra[\big]{x}\ket[\big]{y^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer modern sample]

There is also a definition of `\braket` as an example on page 28 of [the `mathtools` manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf)

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[3]%
  {\langle}%
  {\rangle}%
  {#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}
```

The manual also has an example of setting three arguments within a bra, a ket and in between.

If you want to change the font used only for these delimiters, there is a standard interface for this in `unicode-math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  range={\langle,\rangle,\vert}]

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}

\begin{document}
\[ \bra{x} \ket{y} \quad \bra[\big]{x}\ket[\big]{y^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern / Libertinus sample]

To redefine `\langlw`, `\rangle`, etc. with legacy math fonts is less standardized. It involves loading a symbol alphabet (of which you only have sixteen) and checking its font table.