# Different ⟨,⟩ symbol (scalerel issue)

Tags: brackets, delimiters, scalerel

My teacher uses angle brackets ⟨,⟩ both for inner product and for linear combinations. I'd like to use different, but similar symbols for this scope: so I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\generate}{\scaleobj{0.8}{<}}{\scaleobj{0.8}{>}}
\begin{document}
\(\langle x,y\rangle\) for scalar products, and
\(\generate{U,V}\) for linear combinations.
\end{document}
```

TeXstudio runs and produces the pdf correctly, yet it alerts about a "missing { inserted" anywhere I put the generate command. What's the issue here?

Comment: You can only use delimiter characters (specified as extendable characters in the font) with `DeclarePairedDelimiter` the `\scaleobj` will not work at all (that is, it will not work as a delimiter extending to the size of the content)  Never use a PDF after any tex error.

Comment: What do I do then?

Comment: BTW, mathbbol has a boldface \Langle and \Rangle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David noted, `scalerel` does not use the same approach as an extensible delimiter.  What one can do is embed your delimiters in a `\scaleleftright` macro to achieve something similar.  Here I limit the scale never to extend beyond 2.5ex in width.  At that point, it merely vertically stretches.

EDIT: a vphantom `X` is added to the argument, so that lowercase arguments do not set smaller than uppercase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\generate}[1]{%
  \scaleleftright[2.5ex]{<}{\vphantom{X}#1}{>}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\(\langle x,y\rangle\) for scalar products, and\\
\(\generate{x,y}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{U,V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{\frac{U}{Z},V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{\displaystyle\frac{U}{Z},V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an alternative, if you wanted the bracket height only `.7` times the object height (with a cap `X` as the minimum sized object), you could do this, which also guarantees the bracket is centered around the math axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\generate}[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \vphantom{#1}%
  \scaleleftright[2.5ex]
    {<}
    {\smash{#1}\vcenter{\hbox{\vphantom{$\SavedStyle\scaleobj{.7}{X#1}$}}}}
    {>}%
}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\(\langle x,y\rangle\) for scalar products, and\\
\(\generate{x,y}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{U,V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{\frac{U}{Z},V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{\displaystyle\frac{U}{Z},V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\generate{\int dx,V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\(\displaystyle\generate{\int dx,V}\) for linear combinations.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My main concern with this solution is that \generate{A,B} and \generate{x,y} will have very different looking shapes, while obviously I'd like to guarantee some tolerance in order to make the symbol recognizable. However, I came up with a different solution based on yours: \newcommand{\generate}[1]{\hstretch{0.6}{<} #1 \hstretch{0.6}{>}} seems to give off some good looking braket shape.

Comment: @johncrimes That is an easy fix.  I added a strategically placed `X` in the second solution, that will serve as the minimum height against which to scale.

Comment: @johncrimes I also added a `\vphantom{X}` to the 1st solution to achieve something similar.